# Input character in array using C

Tags: c

I am trying to take characters as input in an array:
My code is:

```
for(i=0;i<n ;i++)
    {
     b[i]= getchar();// scanf("%c",&b[i]) ;// scanf("%c" , v=getchar());
    }
```

I am not getting any input. Can anyone advise me?

Answer (score 3):

using getchar function if you press enter that character also store into that array in that position you should use the scanf(" %c",&b[i]);

Answer (score 0):

When you enter a character followed by a enter there are 2 characters so the newline can be ignored by using.

```
scanf(" %c",&b[i];
```

space before %c

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to fill a character array with characters from a line of text, then `scanf` is a proper tool for the job. As others mentioned, you must insure that the `newline` character `'\n'` (that results from pressing `[enter]`) is stripped from the input buffer, or the next input you try and get will appear to be skipped (it took `'\n'` that remained as your intended input).

For a simple line of text, `scanf` is a correct choice. However, you must provide the correct `format string` that will consume the `newline` or you will need to manually empty the input buffer. Here is an example of one way of doing it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

    char b[50] = {0};        /* always initialize your variables */
    int i = 0;

    printf ("\n Enter all characters for your array: ");

    scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", b);  /* read array b from stdin, discard the newline */

    printf ("\n You entered: '%s'\n\n", b);

    while (b[i]) {
        printf ("  b[%2d] : %c\n", i, b[i]);
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Use/output:**

```
$ ./bin/scanfbasic

 Enter all characters for your array: These are the chars in b.

 You entered: 'These are the chars in b.'

  b[ 0] : T
  b[ 1] : h
  b[ 2] : e
  b[ 3] : s
  b[ 4] : e
  b[ 5] :
  b[ 6] : a
  b[ 7] : r
  b[ 8] : e
  b[ 9] :
  b[10] : t
  b[11] : h
  b[12] : e
  b[13] :
  b[14] : c
  b[15] : h
  b[16] : a
  b[17] : r
  b[18] : s
  b[19] :
  b[20] : i
  b[21] : n
  b[22] :
  b[23] : b
  b[24] : .
```